# Java: Calling static method but nothing happens?

Tags: java, swing, methods, static

I have a class called GUI which basically creates a latout using Swing. In that class i have a method called "log" which is supposed to add a new line to a textarea in the layout.

The problem is that whenever i call the function from outside of the GUI class, nothing happens. If i call the method from within the class it adds a line to the textarea as it's supposed to do.

I have set the method and all the variables it calls to public static, and i don't get any errors. It just doesn't do anything when i call the method from the outside.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Here's the method within the GUI class:

```
public static void log(String inputString) {
    logConsole.append(inputString + "\r\n");
}
```

At the bottom of the class swing declared the textarea, and i just modified it to be public static instead of private.

```
public static javax.swing.JTextArea logConsole;
```

Can't post more code, hope this is at least a little bit helpful? :/

Comment: I left my crystal ball at home.

Comment: Will be hard to answer without pasting relevant code. But you can try to call the method from your outer class by writing Class.theMethod()

Comment: My car doesn't work. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Guys, ease up on the hostility...jeez. @qwerty, for better help sooner, include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org)

Comment: See my edit guys. I can't provide more code, sorry.

Comment: I still don't see enough code to explain your problem.  If mre's excellent suggestion in his answer below doesn't help I second the recommendation for an SSCCE. By the way, regarding "providing code", we don't want to see the entire program, just a small compilable redaction of the program that reproduces your problem. Check out the link in mre's comment above for the details on what this involves. If you can produce and post a good one, you'll usually get a good answer here quickly. Up to you.

Comment: @qwerty, is `log` being invoked outside the EDT?

Answer (score 8):

It's most likely a concurrency issue with Swing. Since Swing is single-threaded, Swing components need to be modified in the Event Dispatch Thread (i.e. EDT). For more information, see [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

---

**EDIT -**

If this is indeed a concurrency issue, then one quick workaround would be to use [`SwingUtilities`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html). In particular, [`isEventDispatchThread()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isEventDispatchThread%28%29) and [`invokeLater(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29). For instance,

```
if(!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            GUI.log("foo"); // modify textarea in EDT
        }
    });
}
else{
    // your problem lies elsewhere
}
```

Comment: To explain further: A line is being appended to `logConsole`.  The problem is that this variable has copies on the cache of each core on your cpu.  You are writing to one copy of `logConsole` on your main thread (one core), but unfortunately the copy that is being put on screen is the copy contained in the Swing EDT (another core).

Comment: Yeah i can't seem to get it to work, i read the documentation mre posted but i don't quite get it atm. Is there a simple way to get this to work?

Comment: I found that i already have that code, except mine didn't have the @Override line, so i added it. Mine didn't have the if state wrapping it either but when i try adding it gives me an "illegal start of type" error... (i have imported the SwingUtilities library) But i'm not sure this is the error either way, cause it should be working by now then?

Comment: @qwerty, The explanation of the error you're receiving was a little confusing to me since the code snippet I provided does not produce such an error. I certainly think you're having a threading issue, and the code snippet I provided ought to resolve this. If it doesn't, then as my comment says, _your problem lies elsewhere_.

Comment: The complete error is here: [link](http://i.imgur.com/adq3Y.png). I also think it's a threading related issue as i've had some problems with it before, nothing like this though. It's so strange because it doesn't give me any errors about it, it just ignores the method call, kind of.

Comment: @qwerty, What Java version are you using? If it's earlier than 1.3, then `isEventDispatchThread()` will not be available!